# How can one re-initiate a "Class"; its static variables

Tags: python, class

I am talking about the Class, not the object. The reason lies that I created a Class which produces some objects but for matters of efficiency I did assign some static variables to some of its methods. In some situations, I want to re-initialise the Class, i.e. set all its static variables to their initial value if any. How can I do that without re-assigning each variable one by one? For instance, if we have the below Class:

```
class tst:
    def lol(self):
        self.lol.__dict__['static_magic'] = True
```

After assigning some objects:

```
# A demonstration of how these work and are the same if one is activated.
>>> a = tst()
>>> b = tst()
>>> a.lol()
>>> a.lol.__dict__
{'static_magic': True}
# Then when running object b (without lol()) has also the variable static magic.
>>> b.lol.__dict__
{'static_magic': True}
```

Afterwards, I decide that is time to re-initiate all its static variables and start assigning from the begging. What I want is the following.

```
>>> c = tst()
>>> c.lol.__dict__
{}
```

What should do? 
Having a copy of the function won't work (static are cross-referenced), deleting and importing also fails and do not looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing to stop you putting your class definition in a function, and simply rerunning the function to recreate the class.

```
>>> def make_foo():
...     global Foo
...     class Foo:
...         X = 'original value'
...
>>> make_foo()
>>> Foo.X
'original value'
>>> Foo.X = 'new value'
>>> Foo.X
'new value'
>>> make_foo()
>>> Foo.X
'original value'
```

Comment: I prefer this answer cause is slick, I can re-initiate everything without clearing each method. Nice hack.

Answer (score 1):

How about to keep it simple, if what you want is to modify the instance not the class:

```
class tst:
    def __init__(self):
        self.statics = {}
    def lol(self):
        self.statics["lol"] = {"static_magic" : True}
```

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/UnwelcomeIllustriousErrors)

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `clear` method:

```
class tst:
    def lol(self):
        self.lol.__dict__['static_magic'] = True
    def clear(self):
        self.lol.__dict__.clear()


a=tst()
b=tst()
a.lol()
print(a.lol.__dict__)
print(b.lol.__dict__)

c=tst()
c.clear()
print(a.lol.__dict__)
print(b.lol.__dict__)
print(c.lol.__dict__)
```

Output:

```
{'static_magic': True}
{'static_magic': True}
{}
{}
{}
```

Comment: Nice, I was looking for this.